# Better SQL Search Engine

Tags: php, mysql, sql, search, search-engine

I have a basic SQL search engine that looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE row_name LIKE '%$keyword%'
```

Using this as a basic search engine works fine however if a person were to misspell of mistype something, it wouldn't work at all. The users query needs to exactly match at least some part of an entry in a database. My question: is there a way to get around this and still return results if someone misspells something. For the computer to return the best results for the search instead of returning nothing. I really want the query to look like

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE row_name MOSTLY LIKE '%$keyword%'
```

There isn't a `MOSTLY LIKE` operator, but I'm wondering what I would use to emulate something like that.
Note: The variable `$keyword` is the users input

Comment: A place to start is by understanding Levenshtein distance (you can google it).  Unfortunately, it is relatively computationally expensive if you have lots of keywords and lots of text.

Answer (score 0):

Look up SOUNDEX if you are using MSSQL.